# Insert into 2 tables at once into mysql databse from arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, textfield

One called Job and the other is called Attributes.  The Attributes table depend on the Job table because One table can have a lot of Attributes.  The job table contains several fields, namely

> Jobid(auto increment, PRIMARY KEY), JobName, Jobdescription

The Attributes table contains the following fields

> id(auto increment, PRIMARY KEY, AttribName, Score, Jobid(Foreign Key from the Job Table).

The number of attributes to be entered per job varies, therefore one job can have 10 attributes, while the other job may have 2, 3,4, etc attributes.

The following is the code I created before I got stuck.

Insert_job.php

```
<?php

include 'html/head.php';//connect to connect to the database and initialize all functions
include 'scripts/functions/init.php';
include 'html/page_title.php';
include 'html/top_menu.php';
include 'titles/Job_insert.php';

if(empty($_POST)=== false)
    {
        $R_fields = array('JobName','JobDesc','JobDuties','RecruitmentProcess','ContractType','SPackage');
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
        {
            if (empty($value) && in_array($key,$R_fields)=== true)
                {
                    $errors[] = 'fields marked with (*) are required';
                    break 1;
                }


        }

        if(empty($errors)=== true)
            {

                if($_POST['DirectorateName'] == '------ select ------')
                    {
                        $errors[] ='Please select Directorate Name';
                    }
                if($_POST['Attributes'] == '-select-')
                    {
                        $errors[] ='Please Select the Number of Attributes';
                    }

            }
    }

    include 'html/job_insert.php';

    //Check if the form is not empty then submit details
    if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors)=== true)
        {
            //store input into the session variables
            $_SESSION['JobName'] = $_POST['JobName'];
            $_SESSION['JobDesc'] = $_POST['JobDesc'];

            //Store the number of attributes to get captured
            $_SESSION['Attributes'] = $_POST['Attributes'];

            //redirect
            header('Location: Rank.php');
            exit();                                                                                                                             
        }
    else if(empty($errors) === false)
        {
            //output errors if the errors array is not empty
            echo output($errors);

        }
?>

                        </div> <!-- div class entry ends here -->
                    </div> <!-- div post ends here -->
                </div> <!-- div idcontents ends here -->
                <!-- end #content -->
                <?php
                    include 'html/top_side.php';
                    include 'html/side_other.php';
                    include 'html/side_bottom.php';
                    include 'html/footer.php';
                ?>
```

You will notice that I store all input into session variables and carry it to the next page where I will insert everything at once into the two tables.

The following code is for Rank.php

```
<?php

include 'scripts/functions/init.php';
include 'html/head.php';
include 'html/page_title.php';
include 'html/top_menu.php';
include 'titles/Rank.php';


//declare the Array to store user input
$job_array = array();

//declare the Array to store attributes
$attributes = array();

//declare the Array to store attributes scores
$scores = array();

//Number of input fields selected by user on Job_insert.php page
$Number = $_SESSION['Attributes'];

//User Input from Job_insert.php page
$JobName    = $_SESSION['JobName'];
$JobDesc    = $_SESSION['JobDesc'];
$JobDuties  = $_SESSION['JobDuties'];
$RProcess   = $_SESSION['RecruitmentProcess'];
$SPackage   = $_SESSION['SPackage'];
$DName      = $_SESSION['DirectorateName'];

//Store user input Job details into an array
$job_array = array(
            'JobName' =>$JobName,
            'JobDesc'=>$JobDesc,
            'JobDuties' =>$JobDuties,
            'RecruitmentProcess'=>$RProcess,                                                
            'SPackage'=>$SPackage,
            'DirectorateName'=>$DName); 




//Check if the form is not empty then submit details
if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors)=== true)
        {
            //submit job details
            job_insert($job_array);                 

            //Store the current jobid into a variable
            $jobid = mysql_insert_id();             

            for($i =0;$i<$Number;$count++)
                {
                    //This is where I am getting stuck
                }

            //redirect
            header('Location: Rank.php');

            exit();                                                                                                                             
        }
    else if(empty($errors) === false)
        {
            //output errors if the errors array is not empty
            echo output($errors);
        }
```

> //output the forms to the screen
>       include 'html/Rank.php';

The following is an example of how I store user input into an array

```
<form action = "" method ="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <fieldset>
                            <?php

                                    if($Number == 10)
                                        {
                                            echo '<table border="0">';
                                            echo '<th>'.'Attribute'.'</th>';
                                            echo '<th>'.'Score'.'</th>';
                                            //Print the first row of the result set
                                            echo '<tr>';
                                            //First Form
                                                echo '<td>'.'<input type="text" size="35" name="attributes[]">'.'</td>';   
                                                echo '<td>'.'<select id="select1" name ="Score[]">
                                                                <option>-select-</option>
                                                                <option>10</option>
                                                                <option>9</option>
                                                                <option>8</option>
                                                                <option>7</option>
                                                                <option>6</option>
                                                                <option>5</option>
                                                                <option>4</option>
                                                                <option>3</option>
                                                                <option>2</option>
                                                                <option>1</option>
                                                            </select>'.'</td>';            
                                                echo '</tr>'; 

                                                //Second Form
                                                echo '<tr>';
                                                echo '<td>'.'<input type="text" size="35" name="attributes[]">'.'</td>';   
                                                echo '<td>'.'<select id="select2" name = "score[]"">
                                                                <option>-select-</option>
                                                                <option>10</option>
                                                                <option>9</option>
                                                                <option>8</option>
                                                                <option>7</option>
                                                                <option>6</option>
                                                                <option>5</option>
                                                                <option>4</option>
                                                                <option>3</option>
                                                                <option>2</option>
                                                                <option>1</option>
                                                            </select>'.'</td>';            
                                                    echo '</tr>';
```

Basically I am storing user input into array called Attributes and another Array Called Score.  insertion of the job details into the job table works fine, but now I need to insert information contained in the Attributes and Score array into the mysql database.  Please assist

Comment: There are so many problems with this code that it's difficult to help. First of all: sanitize input before inserting data into database. Don't include code in the middle of a script. Prepare your libraries and include them. Try to separate html output from php logic.

Comment: I have a function I use to sanitize input, but I do that in a different script then call the function on this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what you mean by

```
//This is where I am getting stuck
```

But you basically want to insert attributes for an already created job. So you can loop through the attributes list and build the query for that.

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO attributes
  (name, score, job_id)
VALUES';

foreach ($_SESSION['Attributes'] as $attribute) {
   $query .= "({$attributep['name']}, {$attribute['score']}, $job_id),";
}
```

Execute that query just like you do inside job_insert.

Comment: Yes, this is more like What I would like to do.  Is possible that you can explain the code inside foreach loop.  Will this automatically insert all values contained in the attributes and score array ?

Comment: It should build a query from all array elements available. Good to hear it works!